# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded Meteor.js form

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have a form that I am submitting (and using a reactiveVar to change the output in the view on submit).  Whenever I submit successfully I get this ominous error:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
isArguments @ es5-shim.js:888
keys @ es5-shim.js:951
_.each._.forEach @ underscore.js:111
EJSON.clone @ ejson.js:500
(anonymous function) @ ejson.js:501
_.each._.forEach @ underscore.js:113
EJSON.clone @ ejson.js:500
(anonymous function) @ ejson.js:501
_.each._.forEach @ underscore.js:113
EJSON.clone @ ejson.js:500
```

I have two event handlers in someview.js:

```
Template.inquiry.events({
  'click .submit': function(event, template) {
    var $form = template.$('#request-form');

    if ($form.valid()) {
          template.showForm.set( false );

          Meteor.setTimeout( function() {
            template.showForm.set( true );
          }, 10000); // Reset after 10 seconds.
    }
  },
});

Template.inquiry.events({
    'submit form': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var name = event.target.name.value;
        var email = event.target.email.value;

        UserList.insert({
            name: name,
            email: email
        });
    }
});
```

and a helper to grab the initial reactiveVar (showForm):

```
Template.inquiry.helpers({

  //toggles 'thank you' on inquiry template
  showForm: function () {
    return Template.instance().showForm.get();
  },
});
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put 2 events triggered at the same time. The moment the button is clicked, the form is submitted as well (I believe the `timeout` is making the recursive calling between the submit and the click), thus giving you the unexpected error. You need to merge those 2 together (and this is natural)

```
Template.inquiry.events({
    'submit form': function(event, template) {

    event.preventDefault();
    var $form = template.$('#request-form');

    if ($form.valid()) {
        var name = event.target.name.value;
        var email = event.target.email.value;

        UserList.insert({
            name: name,
            email: email
        });

        template.showForm.set( false );

        Meteor.setTimeout( function() {
            template.showForm.set( true );
        }, 10000); // Reset after 10 seconds.
    }
}
```

});

and remove the `click` event

Comment: Thank you.  As an aside, is it ok to have this in client/views/thisview.js?  Or should I be moving this logic elsewhere (just for best practices)

Comment: I normally put all things relating to a template into 1 file for easier to control

Comment: do you keep that js file in the same folder as the view/template itself?

Comment: depend on the context. If it is under the same router path, i make the folder like the router path (router `/a/b` then making folder `a/b` and store all the related template of that router under that folder. `html` and `js` of the same template should be put as the same name